# How do I modify the Telemetry session ID in the Application Insights JavaScript SDK?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I have an Angular application which I have configured to use the Application Insights JS SDK. I want to modify the session ID at certain times, which is important to the way I log sessions in my application.

The documentation suggests I add Telemetry initializers as follows; https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-JS#telemetry-initializers

```
var telemetryInitializer = (envelope) => {
  envelope.tags["ai.cloud.role"] = "your role name";
  envelope.tags["ai.cloud.roleInstance"] = "your role instance";
}
appInsights.addTelemetryInitializer(telemetryInitializer);
```

How could this be done to change the session ID?

I went through the docs to see if there are any keys to access to overwrite the session ID, I couldn't find anything there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out how to do it, I was able to look at the request payloads and get the key to edit the session ID for telemetry.

```
var telemetryInitializer = (envelope) => {
  envelope.tags["ai.session.id"] = "my session id";
}

appInsights.addTelemetryInitializer(telemetryInitializer);
```